# serviceworker scope with gcm

Tags: notifications, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have two questions.

(sorry... I don't speak English well. Please help me..)

**This is my situation:**

I know serviceworker only run in scope in url registered range .
but now i found strange situation.

Now i'm making pushserver with gcm and serviceworker.
Now i receive push notification Message on mobile

I didn't open chrome on mobile
so, i didn't access url page that is service worker scope url.
so maybe all service worker state didn't change from stop state to run state
Although all serviceworker state is stop, it is registered on chrome

so all serviceworker would not catch any message .

**Two Questions**

1. How can service worker catch the message on stop state. if
   serviceworker is registered on chrome, then chrome can catch gcm
   message for use gcm registration_id

   I received notification message even though the chrome didn't open
   on mobile

   I'm supposing. Although service worker stop state and out of range
   run url scope, The reason service worker can run is because gcm send
   message to device.

   Did i understand correctly? is it okay?
2. I can't receive notification on pc if off chrome. but i can receive
   notification on mobile if off chrome.

   is it right?

   i want receive notification on chrome off state on pc  What should I
   do.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the reason why you received notification on your mobile but not on PC is because data messages wake the app by default on Android. However, this feature is currently not supported in Chrome.

As discussed in Google Cloud Messaging, with [**content_available**](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream) parameter

> On iOS, use this field to represent content-available in the APNS payload. When a notification or message is sent and this is set to true, an inactive client app is awoken. On Android, data messages wake the app by default. **On Chrome, currently not supported.**

In addition to that, [this part of video](https://youtu.be/_dXBibRO0SM?t=803) regarding Web Push Notifications also mentions that **Chrome currently doesn't support the Web push protocol**.

For more information, you may check [Push Notifications on the Open Web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en)
 and this [video on Web Push Notifications (I/O 2016)](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/video?hl=en) might also help.